# Angular 2 http post not sending body properly

Tags: angular, mongodb

this is  my code im having issues with

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('mongodb://lee:Zzbawsoldd1@ds163630.mlab.com:63630/bookings_drbookings',['bookings']);

router.get('/book', function(req,res,next){

    db.bookings.find(function(err, bookings){
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        }else{
            res.json(bookings);
        }
        
    });
});

// Get Single Todo
router.get('/book/:id', function(req, res, next){
    db.bookings.findOne({
        _id: mongojs.ObjectId(req.params.id)
    }, function(err, todo){
        if(err){
           res.send(err); 
        } else {
           res.json(todo);
        }
    });
});




router.post('/book', function(req, res, next){
    var todo = req.body;
    console.log(todo);
    
    /*if(!todo.text || !(todo.isCompleted + '')){
        res.status(400);
        res.json({
            "error": "Invalid Datazz"
        });
    } else {*/
        db.bookings.save(todo, function(err, result){
            if(err){
                res.send(err); 
            } else {
                res.json(result);
            }
        });
    
});



router.put('/book/:id', function(req, res, next){
    var bookinfo = req.body;
    var updObj = {};
    
    if(bookinfo.isCompleted){
       updObj.isCompleted = bookinfo.isCompleted;
    }
    
    if(bookinfo.text){
        updObj.text = bookinfo.text;
    }
    
    if(!updObj){
        res.status(400);
        res.json({
            "error": "Invalid Data"
        });
    } else {
        db.bookings.update({
            _id: mongojs.ObjectId(req.params.id)
        },updObj, {}, function(err, result){
            if(err){
                res.send(err); 
            } else {
                res.json(result);
            }
        });
    }
});

router.delete('/book/:id', function(req, res, next){
    db.bookings.remove({
        _id: mongojs.ObjectId(req.params.id)
    },'', function(err, result){
        if(err){
            res.send(err); 
        } else {
            res.json(result);
        }
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http , Headers , } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
 
 

@Injectable()
export class BookService {

    constructor(private _http:Http){

    }

    getTodos(){
        return this._http.get('/api/v1/book')
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

    saveBooking(booking){
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

                 
      
        return this._http.post('/api/v1/book' , JSON.stringify({ b: 'texts.value',
      isCompleted: 'b'}), {headers: headers})
            .map(res => res.json());
            
    }
    
}
```

I have a problem with my angular2 application - I created a service to use my post request to `mongodb` however my `req.body` always comes empty.

When I click post it posts to my `mongodb` but there is not data taken from the service.

here is my service and my server requests

*Here is my code:*

[image]

Comment: instead of image link , please paste the code directly

Comment: what version of Angular are you using?

Comment: i am using angular 2

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong http import.

Should be:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
```

Then you no longer need to map to JSON, since it's done automatically. You also don't need to stringify the JSON nor attach those headers, since app/json is set by default now in this HttpClient.

Comment: i tried adding the HttpClient however , the  "'@angular/common/http';" says it is not found in my library , is this because i am using diferent version of angular?

Comment: i am using angular2 not angular 4 , this is only used for angular 4

Answer (score 0):

[HttpClient guide for Angular](https://angular.io/guide/http)

1) You need to use HttpClient instance

2) Headers instances are immutable, sou you need to reassign headers on .append()

3) HttpClient performs JSON.stringify on the payload by default, you don't need to stringify it before sending or you'll have to trim extra pair of quotemarks on the backend.

Comment: I tried adding this to my app however it says it cannot find module , i think im using a different version of angular

Comment: Did you include HttpClientModule in AppModule?

Comment: yes i have included the HttpModule in the AppModule . but i could not add the HttpClientModule since i think it is a different version of angular . because when i add the HttpClientModule it says it cannot be found

Comment: I am using angular2 not angular 4 , this module is only for angular 4